# cannot parse using simple xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing, simple-framework

Hi all im try to parse a xml data stored in a string variable in my android project

MainActivity

```
public class  MainActivity extends Activity {


    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetPropertyService gpservice= new GetPropertyServiceImpl();
        Property p;
        try {
            p=gpservice.getProperty();
            List<PropertyDetails> s = p.getProperty();
            Log.e("SIZE OF S IS",""+s.size());
            //t.setText(""+s.size());
                for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
                {
                Log.e("PR_ID",s.get(i).getPR_ID());
                Log.e("PR_NAME",s.get(i).getPR_NAME());
                Log.e("IMAGE",s.get(i).getIMAGE());
                Log.e("PR_UNITS",s.get(i).getPR_UNITS());
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

GetPropertyService .java

```
public interface GetPropertyService 
{
     Property getProperty() throws Exception;
}
```

GetPropertyServiceImpl.java

```
public class GetPropertyServiceImpl implements GetPropertyService{

    String smp = "<Property><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>58</PR_ID><PR_NAME>SKY LINE</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/090520131119518_MImage.png</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>272</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>59</PR_ID><PR_NAME>Winter Mist</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/200520131154299_MImage.jpg</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>35</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>63</PR_ID><PR_NAME>Q</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/07062013953201_MImage.png</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>6</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>64</PR_ID><PR_NAME>dfytfy</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/220520131737864_MImage.jpg</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>16</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>65</PR_ID> <PR_NAME>rtert</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/270520131435682_MImage.jpg</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>16</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>66</PR_ID><PR_NAME>123</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/04062013955569_MImage.jpg</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>30</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>67</PR_ID><PR_NAME>GFHGH</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/04062013958563_MImage.jpg</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>16</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>68</PR_ID><PR_NAME>1234R</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/04062013101373_MImage.gif</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>30</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>69</PR_ID><PR_NAME>GFHGH11111</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/04062013103287_MImage.jpg</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>16</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>70</PR_ID><PR_NAME>HJKJK</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/04062013109884_MImage.png</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>35</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails><PropertyDetails><PR_ID>71</PR_ID><PR_NAME>fghfg</PR_NAME><IMAGE>~/developer_admin/propertyimages/06062013172473_MImage.jpg</IMAGE><PR_UNITS>16</PR_UNITS></PropertyDetails></Property>";
    private Property domainObject;  

    @Override
    public Property getProperty() throws Exception {

        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(smp.getBytes());
        domainObject = serializer.read(Property.class,
                is, false);


        return domainObject;
    }

}
```

PropertyDetails.java

```
@Root
public class PropertyDetails extends BaseResponse{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Element
    private String PR_ID;

     @Element
    private String PR_NAME;

     @Element
        private String IMAGE;

     @Element
    private String PR_UNITS;




    public String getPR_ID() {
        return PR_ID;
    }
    public void setPR_ID(String pR_ID) {
        PR_ID = pR_ID;
    }
    public String getPR_NAME() {
        return PR_NAME;
    }
    public void setPR_NAME(String pR_NAME) {
        PR_NAME = pR_NAME;
    }
    public String getIMAGE() {
        return IMAGE;
    }
    public void setIMAGE(String iMAGE) {
        IMAGE = iMAGE;
    }
    public String getPR_UNITS() {
        return PR_UNITS;
    }
    public void setPR_UNITS(String pR_UNITS) {
        PR_UNITS = pR_UNITS;
    }
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

Property.java

```
@Root
public class Property extends BaseResponse{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @ElementList (required=false)
    private List< PropertyDetails > property;


    public List<PropertyDetails> getProperty() {
        return property;
    }


    public void setProperty(List<PropertyDetails> property) {
        this.property = property;
    }



}
```

BaseResponse.java

```
@Root
public class BaseResponse implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

These are my setup, but im unable to get the list. What im missing? can any one point me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Property" != property, XML is case sensitive, so you need your element list to have @ElementList(entry="Property", required=false, inline=true)